# Current Knowledge of Superlattices

Tags: lattice-model

What is our current understanding of superlattices (such as how they form, their behavior, their physical properties, etc.)? Second, do they fall under the same laws as typical lattices?

Comment: Can you narrow this down? As it stands it is way too broad, encompassing decades of work.

Comment: Have you read this ?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superlattice